# How get a text size in SP (Scaled Pixel) directly from a TextView?

Tags: android

I`ll wish change the text size in run-time based in the old size.

How get a text size in SP (Scaled Pixel) directly from a TextView?

Something like:

```
textMove.setTextSize(textMove.getTextSPSize()  + sizeFontScale);
```

Answer (score 31):

What about:

> ```
> float px = editext.getTextSize();
> float sp = px / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
> ```

Comment: Made my day!
I was trying to make two buttons with dynamic but equal text size and this was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

So... `setTextSize(int)` actually assumes Scaled Pixels. `getTextSize()` returns the *actual* pixels. If you want to increase by an amount of actual pixels then you can call `getTextSize()`, add whatever, then call `setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, newValue)`. I guess I'm kind of wondering if you really want to do everything in Scaled Pixels.